# Mega menu not displaying correctly

Tags: html, css

I have built a dropdown/ mega menu that works perfectly when placed in the body tags.

However, I want to place it within a specified div.

The code for the div is

```
.menu{width:100%; margin:0 0 50px 0; background-color:#D5D5D5;}
```

When I place the menu within this, the background colour disappears!

What I want is a grey bar with width 100% but then the menu sitting within 960 width. I assume I will need two divs for this.

The overflow needs to be be possible as the menu expands.

Anyone able to help me please!
THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to place the

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

end of the ul list

```
<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

.menu{width:100%; margin:0 0 50px 0; background-color:#D5D5D5;}
.menu ul { margin:0px; padding:0px; }
.menu li { margin:0px; padding:0px; display:inline; }

- asfafa
- asfafa
- asfafa
- asfafa

I thing this will solve your problem